# Split properly a string in python

Tags: python

I have the following string:

`string = '  1234      91          1404  '`

and I would like to split in such a way so that the final output will be:
`1234,91,1404`. Is there an easy way to do so? I have tried the `split` and the `join` commands without any success.

Comment: Please *post* your attempts at solving the problem

Comment: So what did you try *exactly*. Please include that in your question. `str.split` and `str.join` are exactly what you'd use, and I'd classify the solution as trivial.

Comment: Are the number of spaces variable?

Comment: @cdarke Yes, the number of spaces could be random.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
s = '  1234      91          1404  '
output = ','.join(s.split())
print(output)
```

**Output**

```
1234,91,1404
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it the proper way:

```
string = '  1234      91          1404  '
print (','.join(string.split()))
```

Output:

```
1234,91,1404
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regular expression.  I offer this as a different way to do it, `join()` and `split()` is probably more efficient:

```
import re
string = '  1234      91          1404  '
string = ','.join(re.findall(r'(\d+)', string))
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for pointing out!

```
print ",".join(s.split())
```

Comment: This would return a list, not a string.

Comment: Please do familiarise yourself with the features of `str.split()`. There is *no need* to filter when you simply use `None` as the first argument, or no argument at all. This also produces a list, not a comma-separated string without spaces.

Comment: Modified my answer, thanks for pointing out. Still new to stackoverflow.